# HTML - form acting weird. Not redirecting to URL and using GET instead of POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm a CS student and I have a DB project due in less than 24hrs! This is really annoying because I just need to forms to access my DB. Anyway, I have this form that works perfectly, while the second form does not work. Instead of posting and directing to the correct URL the second form re-loads the current page with the variables in the URL. Anybody have any ideas?

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="../controller/AddPerson.php">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newReservationFirstName"> First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newReservationFirstName" placeholder="Enter first name">
            <label for="newReservationLastName"> Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newReservationLastName" placeholder="Enter last name">
            <label for="newReservationPhoneNumber"> Phone Number</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newReservationPhoneNum" data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 999-9999"' data-mask/>
            </div><!-- /.input group -->

            <label for="newReservationStreetAddress"> Street Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newReservationStreetAddress" placeholder="Enter street address">
            <label for="newReservationCity"> City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newReservationCity" placeholder="Enter city">
            <label for="newReservationState"> State</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="newReservationState">
                    <?php
                    $result = getTableOrderBy('States','stateName');
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value=".$row[stateAbbr].">".$row[stateName]."</option>";
                    } ?>
            </select>
            <label for="newReservationZip"> Zip Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newReservationZip" placeholder="Enter zipcode">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add New Customer</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the form that doesn't work correctly, both pages exist on the server:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="../controller/AddEmployee.php">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="newEmployeeFirstName"> First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeeFirstName" placeholder="Enter first name">
            <label for="newEmployeeLastName"> Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeeLastName" placeholder="Enter last name">
            <label for="newEmployeePhoneNumber"> Phone Number</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeePhoneNum" data-inputmask='"mask": "(999) 999-9999"' data-mask/>
            </div><!-- /.input group -->

            <label for="newEmployeeStreetAddress"> Street Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeeStreetAddress" placeholder="Enter street address">
            <label for="newEmployeeCity"> City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeeCity" placeholder="Enter city">
            <label for="newEmployeeState"> State</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="newEmployeeState">
                    <?php
                    $result = getTableOrderBy('States','stateName');
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value=".$row[stateAbbr].">".$row[stateName]."</option>";
                    } ?>
            </select>
            <label for="newEmployeeZip"> Zip Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeeZip" placeholder="Enter zipcode">
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <label for="newEmployeeFirstName"> Account Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeeUsername" placeholder="Enter username">
            <label for="newEmployeeLastName"> Account Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeePassword" placeholder="Enter password">
            <label for="newEmployeePhoneNumber"> Social Security Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newEmployeeSocial" placeholder="Enter SSN">
            <div class="form-group" name="newEmployeePrivileges">
                <br>
                Privileges :
                <select name="newEmployeePrivileges">
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="admin">Non-Admin</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add New Employee</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

----------------------------------EDIT ----------------------------------------------

I tried making a another really simple form on some extra space and it still didn't work. I have no idea what could be cause it to do this.

```
                <form method="post" action="post" action="../controller/AddEmployee.php">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Add New Employee</button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Is the missing closing bracket on "</button" just a copy paste error?

Comment: Maybe its something outside of these forms?

Comment: Are all the above pages at the same path, I.e. Can there all access the post form path?

Comment: yup they are both located in the same folder, at the same level.

Comment: I copied the first whole page and im slowly changing it around that one form. So far its still working, maybe I'll find out what the problem was.

Comment: Maybe access rights problem?

Comment: looks like you should look into ../controller/AddEmployee.php, just make the first line print_r($_POST);exit; and see if you get a white page with your field values printed out

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the button tag you are using to submit the form is causing it behave strangely. Try swapping out the button tag for an input. So:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../controller/AddEmployee.php">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="submit" >Add New Employee</input>
</form>
```

Also, I noticed you've included two 'action' attributes in your example form :-)